# how to get a string from java function in php

Tags: java, php, tomcat, lucene, php-java-bridge

I have written 2 java codes (FullTextIndexer.java and Indexer.java) FullTextIndexer has functions :

```
public static StringBuilder do_exist = null;
public static String do_exist_str;
public static String a_value = new String("my_string");
public static void main(String[] args){ 
    //... here I find "do_exist" value by using "Indexer.java" and printed it with system.out.println; which is the correct value
    do_exist_str = do_exist.toString();
}
public static String get_file()
{
    main(args);
    return do_exist_str;    
}
```

Then I compiled it and compress it as FullTextIndexer.jar and put it into my WEB-INF/lib folder.
And in my php code :

```
require_once("java/Java.inc");
$session = java_session();

$t = new Java('java.lang.System');
$t=new Java("web_java.FullTextIndexer");
$gotten = java_values($t->get_file());
$a_value = java_values($t->a_value);
echo $gotten;
echo sizeof($gotten);
echo $gotten[0].$gotten[1];
```

I expect to get my file_name string however I always get an array like {0=0, 1=0} of size 2. 
But it writes $a_value correctly. 
I guess it finds its value in main(args) but erase afterwards and cannot return "do_exist_str" correctly. 
I cannot find a way to get this string correctly. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not an expert on Java but try dumping the variables to see what they contain, and whether PHP interprets them as objects, arrays, etc. Use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for that.

Comment: Avision thanks for your reply. I have tried them, and see that php see them as a constant array that never changes even if I change the values. And I found that there was no mistake in code but a version problem has occured. When I change my jdk to 1.6 from 1.7, I could solve the problem.